# How change text in button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to do here is have the pushButton in PyQt5 to change to "Working..." and Red when clicked... which it currently does. Thing is I need it to also change back to the default "SCAN" and Green color when done running that method the button is linked to.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import pyautogui



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.showMaximized()
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(3840, 2160))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 85, 127, 100);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 400, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Tahoma")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 300, 701, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 85, 127, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SCAN"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WELCOME"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copy)

    def copy(self, MainWindow):
        self.pushButton.setText('WORKING...')
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        testprompt=storeid=pyautogui.prompt(text='test', title='test')



class Application():
    def run():
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

Application.run()
```

Comment: A screenshot and an explanation of how it is not working would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cant upload a screenshot right now, but this code loads a window with a button that is green and says "SCAN"

when clicked it runs the method "copy" in the same class, which loads a prompt window (just for testing purposes, will eventually run a seperate python file on button click). It shows that prompt, and it changes the button text to "Working..." but after running that method where it does those things, I need it to change back to the default test of  "Ready" and green color.... I hope that made sense :/

Comment: this is a challenge at work, so it would  help me a lot I know my terminology and such is off, but I am just learning, thanks guys

Comment: @MikeNH have you tried to use `self.pushButton.setText('SCAN')` again *after* the line in which you call prompt?

Comment: @musicmante Thank you! so simple... dont know how i missed that. Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `pyautogui.prompt`, I would recommend using one of the Qt classes, like QMessageBox or QInputDialog since you're already using a massive GUI toolkit with tons of widgets and classes.

In the button stylesheet, you can specify the background color to red when the button is disabled. This way you can disable the button, call the dialog window, and then enable it afterwards. The style sheet looks like this:

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('''
QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
QPushButton:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);
}''')
```

And the copy function

```
def copy(self, MainWindow):
    self.pushButton.setText('WORKING...')
    self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
    text, pressed = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Test', 'Test')
    self.pushButton.setText('SCAN')
    self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: thanks, my next question was actually how to disable the button when clicked. Awesome!